# How to text-align center this label text?

Tags: html, css, forms

How do I vertically align center this text?

From:

[image]

To:

[image]

```
<<p>
<label></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" value="Yes" checked="checked">
<label for="checkbox" style="margin-right:10px;"></label>Subscribe me to your mailing list for upcoming events, hot offers and deals
</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JoshSalway/E5CxM/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As counter-intuitive as it might seem, you need to add `vertical-align: middle` to the element you want to vertically align *with*, rather than the element you want to be vertically aligned (in this case, the `label[for=checkbox]`.

See a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/E5CxM/2/

Comment: I prefer this answer as it is more specific then just Label. I just wanted the label for checkbox to be altered.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:-

http://jsfiddle.net/AFGMf/

```
 label
    {
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use line-height to make text vertically centered

```
label{
line-height: 45px;
height: 45px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is a simple example of how it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/E5CxM/10/

Comment: Please provide JSFiddle fork.

Comment: @Josh I made an example, not using your code though. Just to show you the property.

Comment: the Checkbox is not on the left hand side?